# Jenkins Executor Crash when multiple executors are building Flutter Apps in parallel

Tags: flutter, jenkins, gradle, fastlane

Here is the Detailed issue:

We have an app with different flavours, every time we update code and push into a specific branch, Jenkins will run a python script that will call gradle to Build each of these different flavours in separate executors, It was working just fine until we implement flutter as a submodule, for some reason Jenkins' builds will fail whenever I have more than a single executor building the app

Each executor will go through these steps

1.- First we Generate the flutter project:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

2.- Then with fastlane we build one flavour executing the next command

```
bundle exec fastlane buildGuestRelease --env Demo
Fastfile

 before_all do
        gradle(task: 'clean')
    end

    desc "Build the release version of the Guest APP and save to Google Drive"
        lane :buildGuestRelease do
            gradle(
                gradle_path: './gradlew',
                task: ':guest:assemble',
                flavor: ENV['FLAVOR'],
                build_type: 'Release',
                properties: signing_properties,
                flags: '--stacktrace'
            )
            copy_artifacts(
                artifacts: [lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]],
                target_path: '~/Google Drive/someDirectory/somewhere/3 - Mobile/GeneratedAPK'
            )
        end
```

3.- And then Crash!!

Logs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:generateReleaseRFile'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable
   > /home/jenkins/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.5/android/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/release/package-aware-r.txt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:generateReleaseRFile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/jenkins/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.5/android/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/release/package-aware-r.txt
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.SymbolIo.readSymbolListWithPackageName(SymbolIo.java:233)
    at com.android.ide.common.symbols.SymbolIo.loadDependenciesSymbolTables(SymbolIo.java:830)
    at com.android.builder.symbols.SymbolExportUtils.processLibraryMainSymbolTable(SymbolExportUtils.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.GenerateLibraryRFileTask$GenerateLibRFileRunnable.run(GenerateLibraryRFileTask.kt:158)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:49)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 47s
43 actionable tasks: 43 executed
�[0m
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:153:in `shell_error!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:80:in `sh_control_output'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `sh'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/gradle_helper.rb:32:in `trigger'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/gradle.rb:60:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
  Fastfile:33:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in `take_off'
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.3/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_job_handler.py", line 78, in <module>
    general_builder(sys.argv)
  File "python_job_handler.py", line 68, in general_builder
    return subprocess.run([*aux_job_command], cwd='../fastlane', check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bundle', 'exec', 'fastlane', 'buildGuestRelease', '--env', 'Demo']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is my flutter doctor -v

```
flutter doctor -v of the Jenkins machine building the project

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0 at /home/jenkins/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 916c3ac648 (11 days ago), 2020-08-01 09:01:12 -0700
    • Engine revision d6ee1499c2
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-21.10.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /home/jenkins/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/jenkins/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I asked this in the flutter github and I did a test locally,

1.- I made several copies of my project (folders -> Project - Projectcopy - Projectcopy2...)
2.- Build them from the terminal all at the same time..
3.- all of them were successful, however when I use Jenkins to trigger those jobs..

well.. Here I am

aah yeah, this also happens in my Mac jenkins building iOS projects with flutter, I cannot have more than one executor at a given time

Flutter github question(closed)
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63621

Comment: Do you actually have this .txt file

`Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/jenkins/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.5/android/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/release/package-aware-r.txt`

Comment: @mdabdullah the file is written and erased during the build, it means that if I have more than one executor, maybe one of the executors will try to use that file when another of the executors just happened to "clean" it..

Comment: Can you restrict this job to run on only one `slave` with one `executor` and test it? That way, no other executor can come and delete it.

Comment: @mdabdullah right now that is my situation, I can only have one executor in each slave at a given time, which slows down my build queue, my jenkins slaves have enough resources to handle 3 executors at a given time...

Comment: Quick solution: Create one more `slave` . The issue is that `flutter` needs to access this file `package-aware-r.txt`  from the same location during runtime. Putting these in in separate slaves mean they are no longer concurrent builds. Better solution: If you want to access them in a single slave means you can no longer have that file created at run time. You need to check how it runs concurrently in your local machine. Is it possible to convert it into a reference file and store it at a particular location and reference it? Recommendation: https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/

Comment: @mdabdullah i could not convert it into a reference since it is an autogenerated file that get cleaned in every project build (its inside the .pub-cache), I think the best I could do for the moment its use dockers to build the app... what do you think? pros? cons?

Comment: Yes `docker` is the next natural step from here I suppose. There are no cons as such except for the effort involved in creating the `docker images`. You must check `flutter` with docker, it looks feasible `https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-dockerize-flutter-apps/` . I must say, install `docker` directly on the `slave` and do executions there before you bother creating jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, after some digging, I found that the issue is with flutter and how it caches resources, limiting to 1 executor got the problem resolved, I'll investigate with locks to see at what point I can safely allow another execution to commence.